# error in :c++ template function

Tags: c++, class, templates

Hi I try build a tamplate function in vc++ like below:

```
template<class _Fn0,class _Fn1>   void for_each(_Fn0 _Func0,_Fn1 _Func1)
{    
    _Func0(12);
    _Func1(12);

}
```

when I use for _Func0/1 a global function this work propely.

```
void aglobal(int a)
{
    a++;
}
for_each(aglobal,aglobal);
```

but when I use a memeber class function I get error message.

```
class A
{
public:
    void aa(int a)
    {
        a++;
    }
    void bb(int b)
    {
        b++;
    }
    void cc()
    {
        for_each(&A::aa,&A::bb);
    }
};
```

error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
1>         see reference to function template instantiation 'void for_each(_Fn0,_Fn1)' being compiled.

How I can fix this error?

thanks herzl.

Comment: Note that names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter (like `_Fn0` or `_Func0`) are reserved, so you aren't allowed to use them in your code.  Compiler and Standard Library implementations usually use these names internally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`A::aa` and `A::bb` are nonstatic member functions; you are trying to call them as if they were nonmember functions.

A nonstatic member function can only be called on an instance of the object.

To fix it, you can

1. make `aa` and `bb` static, or
2. pass an instance of `A` into `for_each` so that it can call the functions on that instance, or
3. use `std::bind`/`std::tr1::bind`/`boost::bind` to bind the member function to an instance before passing it to the function template, or
4. write a functor that stores a pointer to the instance of `A` on which you want to call the member function and a pointer to the member function that you want to call; this is effectively what `bind` does (though `bind` is far more generic).

Comment: +1 And note that names starting with underscore-capital are reserved by the implementation.

Comment: @herzl: If you wanted to call the two member functions on `this`: `for_each(std::bind(&A::aa, this, std::placeholders::_1), std::bind(&A::bb, this, std::placeholders::_1))`

Comment: @herzl:  Also be very careful:  `std::for_each` is the name of a Standard Library function (in `<algorithm>`).  If you add another argument to your function so it has three arguments and either `using namespace std` or pass arguments that are of types from the Standard Library, you could end up calling the wrong function.

Comment: @James: yes i will change name of this function this only a try name. I understand your example partly How I can use your example?. where define `std::bind` I only see std::bind2nd or std::bind1st.I need few more help to use your example. How I can learn more about `std::bind` thanks

Comment: @herzl: `bind` is a component of the Boost libraries (in `<boost/bind.hpp>`); it is also included in C++ TR1 and C++0x (in `<functional>`). Your compiler may not support either of those yet or may require some flag to enable them.  Most recent compilers support them.  You can learn all about `bind` from [the Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bind/bind.html).

Answer (score 1):

The class's member function always accept extra param "this" pointer, so you can make them static to try this.